# First AJAX-call is faster when debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, debugging

**Problem:**

When I'm in the debugging perspective my first AJAX call is done within under 1s. If I execute the same code without debugging, the first call takes up 1min whereas the subsequent calls are under 1s again.
(reproduced Chrome, Firefox and IE)

**My AJAX call:**

```
var getJSONfromURL = function(url, callback){

    //removed '.ready' according to @adeneo's and @Jeremy_Thille's comments
    //$(document).ready(function(){ 
        var request = $.getJSON(url, callback);

        request.done(function(){
            //something...
        });
    //});
}
```

**Further Details**

- The HTML-document that calls this function takes about 200ms to load.
- The callback-function and the request.done part are executed ~1min after getJSONFromURL finishes.
- A console.log() showed that the getJSON is being called once.
- The same behaviour is being observed when I use XMLHttpRequests. (The ReadyState changes after ~1min.)
- Loading the URL in the Browser takes under 1s.
- The size of the JSON to be loaded is about 500B.
- Both the HTML executing the call and the JSON being requested are on localhost. (The latter is from a MongoDB-NOSQL database REST-API.)
- Concerning JS surrounding this function: This script is being called right after the loading of the HTML. The only time consuming operations that happen before it are the loading of google.charts and jquery.
- No graphics are being loaded on the page.

**Conclusion**

1. Why do I have this discrepancy between the loading times in the two different perspectives?
2. Why does it only happen with the first AJAX call?
3. What can I do to speed up the process?
4. How can I observe what's taking so long without using the debugger?

Thank you in advance for any help, ideas, explanations,...

Comment: Not that it should matter, but you can remove the document.ready, it doesn't really do any good when you're not accessing the DOM, and doesn't really have any business being inside an ajax function like that.

Comment: It may actually matter, because the DomReady event listener is set only _after_ the `getJSONfromURL` function is called. So not only is it useless, but it may even be harmful because it's waiting for an event that's already happened.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I removed it, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Marc you're using `getJSON` both in callback and promise mode at the same time. You're giving it a callback function (that probably doesn't exist) and you're also using the promise mode `.done`. Not sure this is a good thing to do. I'm surprised you didn't mention any error in the console. Try `$.getJSON(url, function(){
            //something...
        });`

Comment: @JeremyThille The callback function does exist. It's storing data from the JSON-file in an array that is not being used jet but necessary for function calls way after the callback finished. (The callback function is not even being fired before about a minute passes.) The `.done` part only fires an `alert()`. Removing it doesn't change anything and both (`callback` and `done`) are being executed... just not as fast as I am expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the AJAX call itself. The REST-API I was calling was buggy. Writing my own RESTful servlet solved the problem.